# Files filter plugin in eclipse (in Package Explorer - Navigator)

Tags: eclipse, filter, directory, filefilter

I want to create a some custom filters for my eclipse project. I think this can be done extending a plugin.

For example .asm file should go to the ASM filter, .c files to the C filter, and so on.

All my input files are stored in the Source folder (on my computer).

But I need this filters only for a better file management, in the Package Explorer.

Please, if anybody have a starting point for this issue ... I will appreciate.

The sooner, the better :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this:
[Eclipse Common Navigator Framework](http://www.techjava.de/topics/2009/04/eclipse-common-navigator-framework/)

And read this tutorial to create a custom navigation:
[Custom Navigator](http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-7-creating-a-custom-navigator/) 
(It's part 7, but in the beginning there is a lot of theory. just find your personal starting point)

I hope this is what you were looking for or that you can at least get something useful out of it...